# selenium Webdriver file upload

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, automation

How to upload file in a pop up..?

[image]

1. First i want to click ACT button
2. Then a pop up will be displayed
   3.Then want to upload a file in that pop up after clicking file upload button present in that pop

[image]

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Answer (score 1):

try to switch to the pop-up

```
 String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
    String childWindowHandler = null;

    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        childWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(childWindowHandler); // switch to popup window


    // perform operations on popup

    try {
        assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[@id='mainDocumentContainer']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td")));
      } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
      }
      try {
        assertEquals("Numéro d'opération :   Epicure 1", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mainDocumentContainer']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td")).getText());
      } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());


   //Back to main window   

    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler); String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
    String childWindowHandler = null;

    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        childWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(childWindowHandler); // switch to popup window


    // perform operations on popup

 try{
```

}catch{

}

```
   //Back to main window   

    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
```

and use this to add your file

driver.findElement(by.Yourlocator).sendKeys("pathToYourFile");

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This pop us not a new window..it's kind of alert or a small pop up where we need to upload documents

Answer (score 0):

You can try driver.switchTo().alert().yourAction();